# Power BI Data Types

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have loaded an xlsx file into power BI. In my data set there are columns that have numbers and text. I don't know how to get power bi to recognize the column a whole numbers. I need this to happen because right now when I sort from highest to lowest it will go like this 1, 11, 2, 29, 4. It only sorts by the first digit and not the whole number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change data types of any column, please click **Edit Queries** option under the **Home tab**.

[image]

Clicking **Edit Queries** option will open a new window called **Power Query Editor**.

Please select the Column for which you want to change the data type. Next, click on the left corner of the column header (currently it represent ABC text)

[image: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/wp-content/uploads/Change-Data-Types-of-a-Column-in-Power-BI-3.png]

Clicking in that position will open a drop-down list of supported data types. Please select the data type that suits your data. Here, we are selecting the Whole number.

[image]

Changing data type of a column will open the following pop up window. Click on the Replace Current button.

[image]

Now you can see the Yearly Income header is displaying 123 (whole number) not ABC (text).